# Problem in Multi dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array which has only 0s and 1s as its values. I want to find the number of occurrences where value 1 is in a linear pair.

Example: 
Below is a matrix (think of it as a multi dimensional array in javascript):

```
1 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
```

And the output i want is the total no. of occurrences of linear pair of 1 horizontally and vertically (not adjacent):

In this case the output is : 3 (one in the first column of first 3 rows. Second is third column of the last two rows. And the last is last three columns in the third row).

Any solution or idea will work. Feel free to use any programming language if not comfortable with javascript.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework problem. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: hey buddy, this is actually a homework and I can access all the values of the given matrix but don't know how to compare its value with its adjacent elements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the predecessor with a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value of the predecessor with a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value and count in both directions.

> It works by looking for a pattern like `0 1 1`, where the last item is the actual position, denoted with `[]`, this must be truthy. The predecessor, denoted with `()` must be truthy as well. The final item, denoted with `{}` is a necessary separator and has to be falsy for counting a starting pattern.
>
> Basically the above pattern is to find and to count in both directions.
>
> Vertical
>
> ```
>  {u} 
> +---------------+
> |(1) 0  1  0  0 |
> |               |
> |[1] 0 {0} 0  0 |
> |               |
> | 1  0 (1) 1  1 |
> |               |
> | 0  0 [1] 0  0 |
> +---------------+
> ```
>
> Horizontal
>
> ```
> +---------------+
> | 1  0  1  0  0 |
> |               |
> | 1  0  0  0  0 |
> |               |
> | 1 {0}(1)[1] 1 |
> |               |
> | 0  0  1  0  0 |
> +---------------+
> ```
>
> ---
>
> `u` means `undefind` and is not part of the matrix

```js
var matrix = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]],
    count = 0;

matrix.forEach((row, i, m) =>
    row.forEach((v, j, r) => {
        if (!v) return;
        if (m[i - 1] && m[i - 1][j] && (!m[i - 2] || !m[i - 2][j])) ++count;
        if (r[j - 1] && !r[j - 2]) ++count;
    })
);

console.log(count);
```

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more!

Comment: @siddhantkumar, sure, please see above.